# Explode splits string incorrectly

Tags: php, explode

Good day!

I use file_get_contents for give answer from remote address and explode for create array give data.

For this i use next code:

```
function test(){
$project_key='fg54gth5k7';
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'code' => $project_key
    )
);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('http://test.com/', false, $context);
return $result;
}

$res = test();
echo $res;

$part=explode(' ',$res);
var_dump($part);
```

**echo $res return row:**

```
3434343 http://test.com/index.php?r=site/stepone
&temptoken=c68c0ae1cece433fe5d6f6578cc0a9b6 OK68 OK Redirect 
http://test.com/index.php?r=site/stepone&temptoken=c68c0ae1cece433fe5d6f6578cc0a9b6 0
```

**var_dump() return array**

```
array(5) { 
[0]=> string(8) "3434343" 
[1]=> string(0) "" 
[2]=> string(0) "" 
[3]=> string(110) "http://test.com/index.php?r=site/stepone
    &temptoken=c68c0ae1cece433fe5d6f6578cc0a9b6 OK68 OK Redirect"

[4]=> string(100) "http://test.com/index.php?
    r=site/stepone&temptoken=c68c0ae1cece433fe5d6f6578cc0a9b6 0 "
```

}

***Tell me please why am I getting the wrong array?***

***array should been next:***

```
array(10) { 
    [0]=> string(8) "3434343" 
    [1]=> string(0) "" 
    [2]=> string(0) "" 
    [3]=> string(110) "http://test.com/index.php?r=site/stepone
        &temptoken=c68c0ae1cece433fe5d6f6578cc0a9b6"
    [4]=> string(4) "OK68 OK Redirect"
    [5]=> string(2) "OK Redirect"
    [6]=> string(8) "Redirect"
    [7]=> string(100) "http://test.com/index.php?
        r=site/stepone&temptoken=c68c0ae1cece433fe5d6f6578cc0a9b6"
    [8]=> string(1) "0"
    [9]=> string(0) ""
```

**Tell me please where error?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They might not be the space character, but tabs etc.

Use [`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with the delimiter `[\s]+`.

> \s stands for "whitespace character". It includes [ \t\r\n] generally.

([Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand))

Comment: Yes. :) I just like the way this looks.